# Index of first element > to a number in a vector with STL::algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a sorted `std::vector<unsigned long long int> myvector` (and all values are different).

What is the shortest way to find the value of the first index `size_t idx` (not an iterator) of myvector strictly > to `MAX_UI32 = 4294967295U`.

For example :

```
[1, 34, 83495, 4294967295, 4294967296, 104000000000] -> idx = 4
[1, 34, 83495, 923834, 912834823, 4294967295] -> idx = 6 (= size of myvector)
```

How to achieve this in one line of code ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [`distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) should do the trick:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned long long int> v;

// ...

return std::distance(v.begin(),
                     std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), MAX_UI32));
```

If there is no such element, `upper_bound` returns `v.end()`, so your result will equal `v.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `upper_bound` in `algorithm`. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that you can use and [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) but in that case you need to write a predicate function:

```
bool IsBigger(unsigned long long int ull) {
  return (ull > MAX_UI32);
}

std::vector<unsigned long long int>::iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsBigger);
size_t index = std::distance(v.begin(), it);
```